# Spearman correlation

Tags: correlation, spss

In correlation, suppose for example we hypothesize that the use of simple words in people with dementia increases over time and a correlation test revealed that this was not true: it decreased over time. Can I conclude with something like "this means that people with dementia use more complex words over time"? If not what test should I use to find if the alternative explanation is right?

Comment: Your set-up is not very clear. For example, Spearman correlation is specific in the title, but not mentioned later. More importantly, what your data are needs more explanation. But the number of simple words and the number of complex words used could both decrease over time. Unless number means percent or proportion, so (presumably) % simple + % complex = 100, the inference would thus  be wrong. As someone with indirect experience of dementia in others, but no clinical expertise, I'd expect all absolute measures of word use to decline.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. An extremely important rule of stats is that absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. Failure to prove your main hypothesis does not in any way signal statistical evidence in favour of the alternative hypothesis.

A few things:

1) Can we really assume from your analytical design and raw data that all non-simple utterances by your people with dementia are “complex” words? How did you handle the coding if for instance the dementia sufferer said something which is not transcribable, i.e. that sounded like just a series of noises, or another language?

2) Assuming your dataset does already code for simple v complex words v unintelligentible sounds or any other important categories, it would be possible to run the same Spearman correlation test on the % coded as “complex” to see if there is an association over time. However, Spearman may not be the best test for re-analysed data depending on how the analysis is grouped/categorised, how many time periods were observed, and sample size. Without more detail on how your data are cut into quantities and perhaps something about the shapes of your distributions, we can’t say which of several tests is most appropriate.

Furthermore, you need to carefully make clear in your reporting irrespective of the test used that this is post-hoc testing secondary to the primary outcome, and was NOT the hypothesis of the initial study. It is probably appropriate to do a Bonferroni correction, i.e. divide your significant p-value by the number of hypotheses you are testing. So if you were targeting p<0.05 and you are now testing 2 rather than 1 hypothesis, really you should only take a finding of p<0.025 as significant for either hypothesis. p<0.167 for 3 hypotheses, p<0.0625 for 4 hypotheses, and so on. This is a grey area with a slippery slope to p-hacking when done post hoc, and the soundest way to deal with your finding would be to run an entirely new study with a new group of people as independent replication of an interesting secondary finding.

3) It’s important to contextualise the broader relevance of your findings. Are you for instance planning to suggest these results can justify building a predictive tool for dementia progression based on speech patterns? As you probably know, semantic context is usually more important to logical meaning than ratios of simple v. complex words used. So % simple v. complex words might pick up people developing dementia, but it might also pick up a lot of false positives, eg people who develop a hobby in scientific or philosophical areas as they get older. Does your dataset as currently analysed have any way of distinguishing between logical and illogical syntax/grammar, irrespective of word choice? If not, be careful on over-interpreting any simple numerical findings.